# Why is the bond energy for a C=O bond higher in CO2?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, carbon-dioxide

I was looking at the table of bond energies, and what caught my eye was how the bond energy for a $\ce{C=O}$ bond is $\pu{736 kJ/mol}$ with the exception of the $\ce{C=O}$ bonds in $\ce{CO2}$ being $\pu{799 kJ/mol}$.

What causes $\ce{CO2}$ to make such a  big difference in a $\ce{C=O}$ bond?

[image: Bond energies]

Comment: That's not a big difference at all. Bond energies only give you a very, very rough estimate.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What a lack of curiosity!! You may be right, but you can probably come up with a better and more interesting answer than that. The presence of noise does not imply the absence of real differences in the signals.

Comment: Can anything be concluded from the resonant structures of CO2? they don't seem to contribute much to the actual structure...